# Postgres почистить базу

Tags: postgresql

При почти полном удалении всех записей размер БД не поменялся.

При том условии что дамп со всеми записями весит в 2 раза меньше пустой.

Аutovacuum включен, но место на диске не чистит

Вариант дамп-дроп-криэйт не предлагать. Туда идет активная запись и простои критичны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А autovacuum и не должен чистить. Он работает как стандартный VACUUM, переиспользует выделенное на диске место.

> The standard form of VACUUM removes dead row versions in tables and
>   indexes and marks the space available for future reuse. However, it
>   will not return the space to the operating system, except in the
>   special case where one or more pages at the end of a table become
>   entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained.

можно выполнить `VACUUM FULL tablename;` но нужно иметь ввиду, что эта штука лочит таблицу. И как я понимаю эту операцию выполняют только в редких случаях, например, данные таблицы скинуты в архив и большинство  строк удалено.

> VACUUM FULL is only needed when you have a table that is mostly dead
>   rows - ie, the vast majority of its contents have been deleted. It
>   should not be used for table optimization or periodic maintenance, as
>   it's generally counterproductive. In most cases the freed space will
>   be promptly re-allocated, possibly increasing file-system-level
>   fragmentation and requiring file system space allocations that're
>   slower than just re-using existing free space within a table.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL

Comment: по поводу скинуты в архив (дамп) - так при создании дампа происходит компрессия и при восстановлении из дампа пустого пространства нет (по крайней мере в 9.3)